# How to find a local maximum and local minimum of a function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My question is related to how to find a local maximum and local minimum.

As far I know, for the first we should find  derivative of the function and set it  to zero. For exmaple, suppose our function is given by:

$$f(x)=x^3+4x^2+5x+6$$

We first differentiate it:

$$f'(x)=3x^2+8x+5$$

For optimal points of $3x^2+8x+5=0$ we find $x_1=-1$  and  $x_2=-5/3$.

For local maximum and/or local minimum, we should choose neighbor points of critical  points, for $x_1=-1$, we choose  two points, $-2$  and $-0$, and after we insert into first equation:

$$f(-2)=4$$

$$f(-1)=-8+16-10+6=4$$

$$f(0)=6$$

So, it means that  points  $x_1=-1$ is local minimum for this case, right? 
Because it has minimum  output among  $-2$ and  $-0$, right?

For this  case, $f(-2)=f(-1)$, but does it change something? Just consider for first point, so if  $f(-1)<f(-2)$, then it means that it would be local minim as well, but if $f(-2)>(-1)$, then it  would be saddle point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Check you zero's again: $x_1 = -1$ is a zero, as is $x_2 = -5/3$.*

Try evaluating $f(x)$ at $x = -3/2$, i.e., $x = -2$ and compare with find $f(-5/3)$

Likewise for $f(-1)$. Choose smaller intervals around each critical point. Try, say, evaluating $f(x)$ at $x = -3/2$ and $x = -1/2$, to compare with $f(-1)$.

Since you have two critical points with only $2/3$ of a unit separating them, you need smaller intervals to determine the behavior of the function near those point.

You can also use the *sign* of the derivative to determine on which interval(s) a function is increasing, and when it is decreasing. When $f'(x) > 0 \implies f(x)$ is increasing, when $f'(x) \lt 0 \implies f(x) $ is decreasing. But again, you'll want to evaluate $f'(x)$ for $x$ very near the critical points $x_1, x_2$

Comment: but actually if  at critical  point  function is maximum among the    two  it's neigbour points,then this point is  called local local maximum right?

Comment: i have update  something (fix up errors in my question ) please see it

Comment: Depends on how far apart your neighbors are.  After all one could take a sine wave function and change it's period so that for each integer value the function was a local maximum so thus you have to be careful about how far apart you are looking at things.

Comment: but let us  suppose that it is not periodic function,just polynomial

Comment: You still need smaller intervals (neighbors closer to the critical points).

Comment: did i choose intervals correctly?

Comment: Read my post for suggested values to use as neighbors.

Comment: Yes, you executed the *process* involved with determining max/min values correctly, just need smaller intervals.  Also, you can tell when a function is increasing or decreasing at a given point by checking the *sign* of the derivative when evaluated at that point.

Comment: yes i have updated my roots

Comment: thanks very much  guys for helping.actually for  real  calculation yes  it is correct  to choose smaller intervals,but  it is for exams  in calculus,so  during exam in genarally it is required  just   as close interval as  for example apart by 1 unit.not too  small  interval

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: thanks ser.i have accept it.thanks this forum so  great help  every time

Comment: Well, in turn, thanks for the effort shown in your post, and the work you did to include it! It's always a pleasure to work with users who are clearly motivated!

Answer (score 2):

Picking nearby points to see if a critical point is a maximum or minimum can be hazardous because the curve might do things you don't expect.  This cubic is very close to flat between the zeros of the derivative.  The reason $f(-2)=f(-1)=4$ is that you have gone over the hill and started down the other side.  You shouldn't pick test points that are beyond another critical point.  If you had tried $f(-\frac 32)=\frac {33}8$ and $f(-\frac 12) =\frac {35}8$ you would see that $-1$ is a minimum.

You could also try the second derivative test to find whether these are maxima or minima.

Comment: so i wanted to understand generall principle.yes of course  we should choose smaller intervals,but generally if   at critical point  function has smallest value then  at  this critical point's near interval,then this point is called local minimum,if maximum has,then local maximum,else saddle point,this is right yes?

Comment: @dato:  that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you graph the given function and particularly look at the behavior of this cubic (with the emphasis on CUBIC), you can tell with the two stationary points you calculated which one is a max and which is min.
You can also look if you want at the derivative, which is quadratic and look at the derivative's graph. When is it above the x-axis and when below?
That tells you which stationary point is a max and which is a min.
Now you try to find out which is which :)